# Setup VPN connection with Synology NAS

Tags: vpn, synology, pppd

I want my Synology NAS (located at home) to be connected to my VPN on the WAN. This allow to keep alive a VPN from home to wan without worring about dynamic IP.

I setup a ppdpd server on my VPN (wheezy) and configured the same on the NAS. Everything works, I can establish a connection from the NAS to the VPS.

Unfortunately this is pretty much all I can do. I unable to ping the NAS from the VPS, but the opposite is OK.

```
Mar 20 23:36:15 foo pppd[16170]: pppd 2.4.6 started by root, uid 0
Mar 20 23:36:15 foo pppd[16170]: Using interface ppp0
Mar 20 23:36:15 foo pppd[16170]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/2
Mar 20 23:36:15 foo pppd[16170]: peer from calling number x.x.x.x authorized
Mar 20 23:36:15 foo pppd[16170]: MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
Mar 20 23:36:15 foo pppd[16170]: Cannot determine ethernet address for proxy ARP
Mar 20 23:36:15 foo pppd[16170]: local  IP address 10.8.0.10
Mar 20 23:36:15 foo pppd[16170]: remote IP address 10.8.0.234
Mar 20 23:36:17 foo ntpd[21240]: Listen normally on 9 ppp0 10.8.0.10 UDP 123
Mar 20 23:36:17 foo ntpd[21240]: peers refreshed
```

Do I need to configure something else (like iptables)? How to diagnostic my issue?

Comment: Just FIY: PPTP encryption can be broken in a matter of hours http://security.stackexchange.com/a/47524

Comment: I know it's weak encryption but I just want to solve the issue before switching to IPsec or open-vpn